# Installing Openstack/Base with juju on MaaS not succeeding because of perceived lxd mount error

Tags: server, juju, maas, openstack

I have installed four servers with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-31-generic x86_64)
 on a maas cloud, whose main server is also running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-31-generic x86_64) on a desktop, and am now trying to deploy openstack through the juju base charm. However, the ovn-central units and the ovn-chassis units are in a blocked state, the message being `'certificates' missing`.
Vault is installed, unsealed and running. I have also double-checked the certificate relation. When I ssh into the ovn-central containers and do `journalctl -p err -b`, I get

```
May 26 22:24:26 juju-58128b-0-lxd-5 systemd[4316]: snap-snapd-7264.mount: Failed to set up kernel keyring: Required key not available
May 26 22:24:26 juju-58128b-0-lxd-5 systemd[4316]: snap-snapd-7264.mount: Failed at step KEYRING spawning /bin/mount: Required key not available
May 26 22:24:26 juju-58128b-0-lxd-5 systemd[1]: Failed to mount Mount unit for snapd, revision 7264.
May 26 22:37:48 juju-58128b-0-lxd-5 systemd-udevd[6433]: Failed to chown '/dev/net/tun' 0 0: Operation not permitted
May 26 22:37:48 juju-58128b-0-lxd-5 systemd-udevd[6433]: Failed to apply permissions on static device nodes: Operation not permitted
May 26 22:38:09 juju-58128b-0-lxd-5 systemd[1]: Failed to start Execute cloud user/final scripts.
May 27 08:56:34 juju-58128b-0-lxd-5 systemd[185756]: snap-lxd-15161.mount: Failed to link user keyring into session keyring: Required key not available
May 27 08:56:34 juju-58128b-0-lxd-5 systemd[185756]: snap-lxd-15161.mount: Failed to set up kernel keyring: Required key not available
May 27 08:56:34 juju-58128b-0-lxd-5 systemd[185756]: snap-lxd-15161.mount: Failed at step KEYRING spawning /bin/mount: Required key not available
May 27 08:56:34 juju-58128b-0-lxd-5 systemd[1]: Failed to mount Mount unit for lxd, revision 15161.
```

Can anyone make sense of this error ?

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit] as this is a Q&A site, not a general forum, so things work differently here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to unsealing vault, before it will issue certificates to your deployment, you must either tell it to generate a root CA or upload a intermediate root certificate. There is more information on how to do this in the Certificate Life Management [0] appendix of the OpenStack Charms Deployment Guide [1].

0: https://docs.openstack.org/project-deploy-guide/charm-deployment-guide/latest/app-certificate-management.html
1: https://docs.openstack.org/project-deploy-guide/charm-deployment-guide/latest/